insert variable in quotes
i have got some code, who make request via requests module in python. but if i try to change 12345 by variable, i get error. Please help me
This code is work
json_data = {
    'commandOrQueryName': 'GetProductByVendorCodeQuery',
    'input': '{"Product: "12345","StoresCodes":null}'
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.com',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
)
print(response.text)

This code not work
art = 0000
json_data = {
    'commandOrQueryName': 'GetProductByVendorCodeQuery',
    'input': f'{"Product: "{art}","StoresCodes":null}'
}

error:
'input': f'{"Product": "{art}","StoresCodes":null}'
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Invalid format specifier ' "0","StoresCodes":null' for object of type 'str'

I try all that i know

In your f-string, you need to double the curly braces that are intended to be passed through, rather than interpreted as a variable to be inserted.

You need to escape the outermost braces in the f-string.  f'{{"Product: "{art}","StoresCodes":null}}'

you can use repr to avoid one quote problem f'{{"Product": {art!r},"StoresCodes":null}}'

in both variants, i get variable without braces json data {'commandOrQueryName': 'GetProductByVendorCodeQuery', 'input': '{"Product": 82199296,"StoresCodes
":null}'}

Thanks all! i add " " and it works!
